# A world 'similar' to ours

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-worlds, worldbuilding-resources

According to a [Ted Ed video about Creating fictional worlds](http://ed.ted.com/lessons/how-to-build-a-fictional-world-kate-messner), if they are created all the time in people's minds.

What audience would a world (for example) where our favourite foods are names of plants and animals such as the drink Mountain Dew being the equivalent to the Mountain Dewbirth plant in another, or literal raining DVD cases and cooking sauces appeal to.

Comment: Hello Edmund, and welcome to Worldbuilding. Two things: 1) your question is a **meta-question** about Worldbuilding. We have a forum for that too, and you are very welcome to post your question there. 2) Your question is kind of confusing. I am not really sure what you are asking. Please consider editing the question to make it more understandable. Adding a link to that Ted Ed talk is probably a good idea too. :) For more information on what makes up a good Worldbuilding question, please see this link: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question

Comment: Please reopen this question, I changed it - if it's still complex I can keep editing

Comment: Edmund, it is still very fuzzy and unclear what it is you actually want to know. I don't even know what you mean by "if they are created all the time in people's minds." because that does not really connect with the first part of that sentence. And when you say "for example" it just makes it even more confusing. Are you asking about absurd worlds in general or about **that specific** absurd world? And what kind of insight is it you wish to gain by the answer?

Comment: Just absurd worlds

Comment: What's 'that specific'?

Comment: And what do you want to know about absurd worlds in the context of Worldbuilding? What kind of people wish to build them, or what kind of people wish to partake of them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: What audience would a world? I feel like there is something missing in your question.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but these worlds... Are for writing about - audience is who reads about these worlds in stories